# Create all directories in specified path

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, filepath

I am using install shield 2014.

On one step user specify path for some files. He/She can set path that consist of folders that not exist.

For example:

> F://folder1/folder2/folder3

But **folder1**, **folder2**, **folder3** not exist on disk F.

Is it possible to tell InstallShield to **create all** (folder1, folder2, folder3) directories that not exist on disk?

Answer (score 0):

This happens automatically all the time.  For example any given installer typically gets set to  C:\Program Files\Company\Product and then files and folders are added to Product.   MSI will automatically create the parent folder Company (and Program Files if it somehow didn't work )  as it's implicitly required to create the Product folder.

Comment: Looks like it doesn't work in my case. If I specify C:\Program Files\MyFolder - MyFolder will be created. But if I specify C:\Program Files\MyFolder\SubFolder - it will not create any folder.

Comment: It's hard to say what you are doing wrong as you haven't posted any source code, build MSI or log files to look at.  I'm telling you what the known, expected behavior is.